# Как расшифровать AES-256 CBC?

Tags: php, java, android, криптография, aes

Есть данный код ( Java ), который шифрует определенный текст:

```
    public String encrypt(String plainText, String password) throws Exception
{
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding");
    key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    spec = getIV();

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
    return encryptedText;
}
public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV() //get iv
{
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    return ivParameterSpec;
}
```

Как можно расшифровать полученный текст на сервере с помощью php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы расшифровать текст, вам необходимо провести обратные операции: декодировать из base64, получить массив байт, декодировать массив использую пароль и вектор инициализации (пример либы https://github.com/lt/PHP-AES), и преобразовать декодированный массив в строку.